# write label from StringBuilder to .doc file aspx.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need help here.I don't know how to tell to labels from different stringBuilder to go on different .doc files.In my if() statements in need to tell to write labels from first stringBuilder and in another if() statement should write labels from another stingBuilder in another .doc file. Below is my code:

```
          StringBuilder strBody = new StringBuilder();
          StringBuilder strBody1 = new StringBuilder();



        strBody.Append(@"<html " +
        "xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' " +
        "xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word'" +
        "xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>" +
        "<head><title>Time</title>");

        strBody1.Append(@"<html " +
        "xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' " +
        "xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word'" +
        "xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>" +
        "<head><title>Time</title>");



        strBody.Append("<body lang=EN-US style='tab-interval:.5in'>" +

                                "<p style='color:red; font-size:13px'>" + 
                                Label47.Text +"<br/>" +  
                                Label45.Text +"X   "+
                                Label48.Text +"   " +
                                Label54.Text +"</p>" +
                                "</div></body></html>").Append(strBody1.ToString());


         strBody1.Append("<body lang=EN-US style='tab-interval:.5in'>" +

                                "<p style='color:red; font-size:13px'>" + 
                                Label12.Text +"<br/>" +  
                                Label11.Text +"X   "+
                                Label13.Text +"   " +
                                Label17.Text +"</p>" +
                                "</div></body></html>");



        if (Session["one"] != null && Session["two"] != null && Session["three"] != null)
        {
            {
                string path = @"c:\Backup\kitchen.doc";
                string path2 = @"c:\Backup\bar.doc";

                if (!File.Exists(path) && !File.Exists(path2))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
                    {

                        using (StreamWriter sw2 = File.CreateText(path2))
                        {

                            if (Label53.Text == "4")
                            {

                                sw.WriteLine(strBody);

                            }

                            else  if (Label53.Text == "1")
                            {
                              sw2.WriteLine(strBody);

                            if (Label44.Text == "4")
                            {

                               sw.WriteLine(strBody1);

                                }

                            else if (Label44.Text == "1")
                            {

                                 sw2.WriteLine(strBody1);

                             }

                        }
```

Comment: Someone could help me here?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I don't get error, but in mu .doc file it written just one label :(

Comment: What is the expected output you are trying to achieve? For specific input values on the Label fields - what should be written to each doc file?

Comment: in first document kitchen.doc should be written all label values from first  StringBuilder strBody , and in the other bar.doc file all labels from second StringBuilder strBody1

Comment: The code is total mess. My advice: go back to the drawing board. Think carefully what is the goal. Construct proper logic first, then write code implementing the logic. Use meaningful names for your elements and variables.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard , I know it's mess, but could you tell me then how to write labels with another color and size in .doc file,half of my labels should go in one .doc and the rest in another .doc file

Comment: @buba color is defined in the style i.e. `color:red` so just change "red" to whatever color you want instead. Also, you already put part of the labels in `strBody` and the others in `strBody1` so just use those. Can't really explain any better, it's all matter of tweaking what you already have.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a missing closing `}` in your `if` conditions. The

```
else  if (Label53.Text == "1")
```

did not have a closing `}`

Updated `if` conditions

```
if (Label53.Text == "4")
{
   sw.WriteLine(strBody);
}
else if (Label53.Text == "1")
{
   sw2.WriteLine(strBody);
}

if (Label44.Text == "4")
{
   sw.WriteLine(strBody1);
}
else if (Label44.Text == "1")
{
   sw2.WriteLine(strBody1);
}
```